# How to send email in regional language use codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send email in our regional language use codeigntier.  I'm using the following script for sending email `$this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); /* for some reason it is needed */
    $this->email->from('no-reply@domainname.com', 'TEST');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Registration Completed Successfully');
     $this->email->message('Welcome message');
    if($this->email->send())
      {
         echo 'success';
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'Sorry, Mail is not send';
        }`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There's no settings in the email configuration for language. I am not too sure what you mean. Have a look in the user guide to see if this helps you; https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: Actually i want to send the email message in our regional language tamil, and also is not user input default fixed message like reminder send to customer in mean while.

Answer (score 0):

To use different languages in CodeIgniter, you can do these two things :

1) Create a language changer in your website

2) Store user preference in the session, and at e-mail creation, load the corresponding language file

```
$this->lang->load('my_email_file',$this->session->userdata('language'));
```

Hope it helps.